# Close a command prompt after completing a task

Tags: batch-file

**Build.bat**

```
@echo off
echo Disabling UAC, please wait...
start DisableUAC.lnk
echo UAC Disabled Successfully!
echo.
pause
```

**DisableUAC.bat:**

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

To run `DisableUAC.bat` with administrative privileges, I created a shortcut `DisableUAC.lnk` and checked properties > shortcut > advanced and checked "Run as administrator." Then I call for it inside `Build.bat`

This all works, but how can I get the command prompt that shows up from `DisableUAC.bat` to close upon completing the task? (keep the main Build.bat open, close the DisableUAC.bat that pops up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `/k` to `/c`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

See `cmd /?`:

> Starts a new instance of the Windows command interpreter
>
> CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
>       [[/S] [/C | /K] string]
>
> /C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
>   /K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
>   ..

Although I don't think you need to start a new cmd.exe at all here? I think this would also work, either directly as a shortcut or in DisableUAC.bat:

```
%windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d
```